# Can't get the images from an API to show up

Tags: javascript

I'm using an API to get information for a database sort of thing. I want the images to be displayed to the right of the text but the images aren't showing up at all. I tried multiple different keys and still nothing. Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

The images are not showing up as you can see.

Here is the JS (its pulling the data from here https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/347/episodes):

```
// DATABASE  const sunnyList = document.getElementById('sunnyList'); let sunnyInfo = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {   const searchTarget = e.target.value.toLowerCase();   const filteredSunny = sunnyInfo.filter(sunny => {
    return sunny.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTarget) || sunny.airdate.toLowerCase().includes(searchTarget) || sunny.airtime.includes(searchTarget)    });

  displayInfo(filteredSunny); });

const loadLayout = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/347/episodes');
        sunnyInfo = await res.json();
        displayInfo(sunnyInfo);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } };

const displayInfo = (sunny) => {
    const htmlString = sunny
        .map((sunny) => {
            return `
            <li class="character">
              <div class="detail">
                <h2>${sunny.name}</h2>
                <p>Season ${sunny.season} Episode ${sunny.number}</p>
                <p>${sunny.airdate}</p>
                <p>${sunny.airtime}</p>
                <p>${sunny.rating.average}</p>
              </div>
                <img src="${sunny.image}"></img>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    sunnyList.innerHTML = htmlString; };

loadLayout();
```

I've tried `sunny.image.medium` and `sunny.image.original` but it still doesn't show up.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you check your network tab and see availability of images in image section, does it give 404?

Comment: your .image is an object with two values inside. medium and original, so chose one. If you have just opened your api URL you would notice that, or console.log sunny.image

Comment: [`image` is an object.](https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/347/episodes) You need to get either the "medium" or "original" value from it. Use your devtools (F12) to help debug situations like this.

Comment: When I replace the <img src="${sunny.image}"></img> with <img src="${sunny.image.medium}"></img> I get a TypeError that says "sunny.image is null."

Comment: Image is a self closing tag

Comment: There are 4 entries in the array without images. You'll need to implement logic to exclude the `<img>` tag for them (or use a default placeholder)

Comment: @Snake_py oh yeah lol, that was an oversight on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `image` is not a url string, but an object with the following shape:

```
{
    medium: string,
    original: string
}
```

where both strings contain the actual image URLs.

For your use case `medium` probably makes more sense, so you can do this:

```
<img src="${sunny.image?.medium}"></img>
```

**Edit**

Added optional chaining because some items do not have `image` property.

Comment: When I use the code you provided I get a TypeError that says "sunny.image" is null.

Comment: Apparently not all of the items have `image`s, so you need to check that it actually has `image`. A simple way is to use optional chaining, like I showed in the edit, but in this case you'll still get broken images, you may add a check that image is "truthy", and then if it is "falsy" change `<img>` to somethig else, e.g. `<div>No image available</div>` or just not show anything at all.

Comment: Wow. Very new so I may be missing something, but it seems to show all the available images. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem your are facing is that not all objects have images.

Please try this code:

```
const displayInfo = (sunny) => {
    const htmlString = sunny
        .map((sunny) => {
          const img = sunny.image ? sunny.image.medium : "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
            return `
            <li class="character">
              <div class="detail">
                <h2>${sunny.name}</h2>
                <p>Season ${sunny.season} Episode ${sunny.number}</p>
                <p>${sunny.airdate}</p>
                <p>${sunny.airtime}</p>
                <p>${sunny.rating.average}</p>
              </div>
                <img src=${img} />
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    sunnyList.innerHTML = htmlString; };
```